# incorrect url showing after magento 2 fresh installation with backend login error

Tags: url, wamp, backend, magento2, magento-2.0

I have installed the newest version of magento 2.0 in wamp environnement. Enabled a lot of php and apache module needed to run it . such like rewrite module and mcrypt.so .
I'm using wamp and the php version used is 5.5 and apache 2.4 . 
I still have incorrect url when I navigate in this fresh installation .
They are like :
example **backend login**

```
http://domain/admin_ping/admin/index/index/key/af9c4250635a6d9ff365d4f4eb65bffd75a032bac/
```

**forgot password**

```
http://domain/admin_ping/admin/auth/forgotpassword/
```

although I'm sure that I have the right login/password, I can't login to the backend I have this error :

```
You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.
```

Comment: try just http://domain/admin_ping/

Comment: I'm redirected to this url 
http://domain/admin_ping/admin/index/index/key/af9c4250635a6d9ff365d4f4eb65bffd75a032bac/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with the magento setup, when you install magento first time, and set a password and confirmation password, is that it stores a wrong password in the database.

**Solution**

edit the file:
`\vendor\zendframework\zend-crypt\src\Utils.php`

and echo the variables `$expected` and `$actual` and check if they have equal values.

if yes, they do not match; change line 35:

```
if (function_exists('hash_equals')) {
    return hash_equals($expected, $actual);
}
```

**To**

```
if (function_exists('hash_equals')) {
    return true;
}
```

for direct access to magento admin with any password, and then change password and revert back the code changes.

This solution worked for me.